# Car return / relocation services in Canada?

Tags: canada, car-rentals

In New Zealand there are car return / relocation services like [Transfercar](http://www.transfercar.co.nz/) which allow you to find one that a rental company wants moved from A to B, and you do it for them, often at very minimal cost to you - they'll sometimes even cover the fuel charges.

I was wondering if a similar service existed for travellers in Canada?

Comment: I can't really answer this question, but this summer when I spent some time in Canada I extensively searched for such services but couldn't find one.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException finally found one, about to add an answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So while in a hostel in Calgary, I have just noticed a poster for [Hit The Road](http://hittheroad.ca/), a Canadian Car Relocations service in Canada.  It looks exactly like what I've been searching for, and offers cars for common destinations and routes in both Canada and the US.

Answer (score 8):

There are such deals!
Here is a [Link](http://www.cruisecanada.com/rent/hot_deals/) to Cruise Canada, (click on the last link on the page "Free rentals from Western to Eastern Canada") they rent out RV's for cross Canada transfers.
They give you an allotment of 6k kilometers and 21 nights to complete the journey (hey that's a free hotel!)

It would seem that currently there are no one way West->East transfers available, but you can also check out the 50% off one way specials (you can save up to 90% = practically free.)

Comment: Amazing find! Although I take it you mean there are no east->west transfers, as there are certainly Vancouver->Toronto options, for example...?

Comment: @MarkMayo see the dates for the free one way West>East, it seems there aren't any active ones now. You would have to check back for new posts. But you can still find some of the 90% off. Correct I haven't seen any East>West transfers.